# Do Interfaces provide specific meaning to objects in Java

Tags: java, serialization, interface

I have a doubt about Interfaces in JAVA:

When a class implements an interface, does anything happen to it if it does not implement its methods? Merely implementing the interface , does it provide any change of meaning to the class ?

For example I have two classes, `Test1` and `Test2`

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable { 
}


public class Test2 {          
}
```

Except for the fact that `Test1` implements `Serializable`, the classes `Test1` and `Test2` are identical. In that case would there be any difference between the functionalities/properties of objects of `Test1` and `Test2`? Would it be possible to break down objects of `Test1` class into bytes (just because class `Test1`implements Serializable)?

If yes, then that means implementing an interface provides some additional meaning to the objects of that class?

Comment: Serializable is kind of a special case (called a marker interface), in that it has no method signatures in it. The only reason why you would implement it is to tell the JVM how to serialize the object (Externalizable is an interface where you can provide your own class specific implementation of serialize and deserialize. These marker interfaces were created early in Java's history, today an Annotation would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from documentaion of `Serializable` -

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
>   The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only
>   to identify the semantics of being serializable.

[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Q1> **In that case would there be any difference between the functionalities/properties of objects of Test1 and Test2**?

`Serializable` is marker interface, which means there no method or field.

Q2> **Would it be possible to break down Objects of Test1 class into bytes (just because class Test1 implements Serializable**?

Yes.

Q3> **If yes, then that means implementing an interface provides some additional meaning to the objects of that class**?

> Object Serialization produces a stream with information about the Java
>   classes for the objects which are being saved. For serializable
>   objects, sufficient information is kept to restore those objects even
>   if a different (but compatible) version of the implementation of the
>   class is present.

Thhe class can optionally define the following methods:

- A writeObject method to control what information is saved or to
  append additional information to the stream
- A readObject method either to read the information written by the
  corresponding writeObject method or to update the state of the object
  after it has been restored
- A writeReplace method to allow a class to nominate a replacement
  object to be written to the stream

[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6428)

Comment: Thank you. My doubt was precisely this - implementing the interface changes the nature of objects of the class?? Correct?? But a next doubt is  user defined interface (custom) interface can (?) only provide some methods to inherit whereas Java in built interfaces can help us to change the nature/properties of the objects of the class... why this difference? Or Am I mistaken somewhere??? (I do not know of any way in which user defined interface can alter the nature/properties of the objects of the class, it just enables to inherit some methods I guess)...

Comment: its compiler and its implicit behavior that takes care of this.

Comment: Yes -- http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/01/what-is-marker-interfaces-in-java-and.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the definition of the interface you decide to implement.
In the example you took one of the classes implemented serializable interface; it being a marker interface you did not have to overload any of its method. But there is as you know a difference between the two classes, while objects of Test1 class can be converted to stream of bytes for external storage such feature is not available for Test2 objects. Also, there is    a serialId class member which Test1 has but Test2 does not.

This was a specific case; but lets say the interface you implemented had abstract methods, then in this case Test1 class  either had to also be an abstract class or it had to provide a concrete definition to those abstract methods of the interface. In such a scenario Test1 and Test2 classes would have varied a lot from each other. FYI,The interface body can contain abstract methods, default methods, and static methods.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+ it's possible for an interface to provide a default method. For [example 13.5.6-1. Adding A Default Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#d5e19889) (which means an interface can add method implementations),

> ```
> interface Painter {
>     default void draw() {
>         System.out.println("Here's a picture...");
>     }
> }
> ```

However, [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) (and Wikipedia says, in part) *the mere presence of such an interface indicates specific behavior on the part of the implementing class*. You might want to compare it to [`Externalizable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html).

Answer (score 1):

An interface, in its most basic form, is a set of empty methods which define some core functions. A class which implements an interface will be required to include all of its methods.

However, interface `Serializable` does not have any methods. It simply states "this object can be serialized," and they sometimes rely on other special methods (`readObject()`, `writeObject()`, etc.) for handling.

Here's a quote from [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. 
>   The serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only
>   to identify the semantics of being serializable.

Therefore a class can only be serialized if it implements interface `Serializable`.

Comment: Suppose I have empty implementations for writeObject(), readObject() etc , even then would it be possible to break down objects of class Test1 into bytes (ie would it be possible to Serialize it)? My question is precisely it - does merely implementing an interface does the job? .... does merely implementing an interface change the nature of the objects of the class?  Thank You..

Comment: @RanN I have made a few revisions. Serializable does not have any methods, so it simply states that the object can be serialized.